# ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer/fesm5/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer.js

Tags: reporting-services, angular7

I am trying to install SSRS report viewer package to my angular project I tried to add Report Module reference to  app.module.ts file then I popup with this error

"ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer/fesm5/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer.js"
The command that I used to install package "npm i ngx-ssrs-reportviewer"

What is the mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version compatibility between angular cli and report viewer is the issue for above error.
Angular Cli Version 1.3.0 and ngx-ssrs-reportviewer version 1.0.2 will works for me.